# Possible to write $N$-partite W state as sum of less than $N$ product states?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

The $N$-qubit W state is $|W\rangle = \sum_{n=1}^N |n\rangle$ where 
$$|n\rangle \equiv |0\rangle_1\cdots|0\rangle_{n-1}|1\rangle_n |0\rangle_{n+1} \cdots |0\rangle_{N}$$
is the product state with the $n$'th qubit in the $|1\rangle$ state and all others in the $|0\rangle$ state.  **Is it possible to express this state as $|W\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{M} |A_i\rangle$ for some set of $M$ product states $|A_i\rangle$ if $M<N$?** I strongly think the answer is no, but can't find a proof.

Smells like a homework problem, but it's not.  Here's what I've tried.

We observe that ${}_N \langle  0 |W \rangle$ is the $(N-1)$-qubit W state while ${}_N \langle  1 |W \rangle = |0\rangle_1\cdots|0\rangle_{N-1}$ is $N-1$ zeros, so it's tempting to make an argument by induction, but it's hard because the inductive assumption only tells you the $(N-1)$-qubit W state can't be expressed as $N-1$ product states, not $N$ of them, and we can't assume the all-zeros state is one of the product state.

I've also tried finding some matrix that can be constructed out of $|W\rangle$ (e.g., using traces or partial inner products) that has rank $N$ in the hopes of arguing that this can't work for a sum of $N-1$ product states (each of which would correspond to rank-1 projectors), but this also has been unsuccessful.

Finally, it's tedious but straightforward to show this for the case $N=3$ by just decomposing the state exhaustively with Schmidt decompositions (e.g., [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0003050.pdf)), but this is inelegant and not easily extendable to $N>3$.

Comment: Not an answer, but for multiple copies of the W state, this can be done with less product states and is related to tensor rank of matrix multiplication, see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.2977

Comment: For the $N=3$ case, another (less elementary but more general) proof is given in [Dür Vidal and Cirac](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0005115), which show that $W$ states are genuinely trifold entangled. In the last section they also consider the entanglement of the $W$ state in in arbitrary dimensions, so you might find the answer to your question there